# Mariadb-server is not installed but cannot install it.

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql, mariadb

I user Ubuntu 16.04 and I updated to mariadb. I installed the package the following way `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client`. Then I tried to use `sudo systemctl start/stop mariadb` but I get the following error:

```
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.
```

I checked if the mariadb-server is installed with the following command `rpm -q mariadb-server` and system tells me tha this package is not installed. If i ran `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`, system tells me that the newest version is already installed. I can use it by typing `sudo mysql -u root -p` but I can't start/stop the service. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo systemctl start/stop mariadb` is the wrong command.

`sudo service mysql start` to start and `sudo service mysql stop` to stop mariadb (it is a mysql clone).

Comment: In some site I will see this command: `sudo systemctl start mariadb.service` and 
`sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service`.